# Laravel - architecture problem with calculating votes for comments

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a bit of an architecture problem with my website.

My website has submissions, and submissions have comments.

Comments have upvotes and downvotes. You can also cancel your upvote or downvote. Exactly like reddit.com

The way I register votes right now, the user votes, and then on the front end that vote is cached so that if the user refreshes the page the vote is shown.

But all that has happened on the back end is that the vote has been registered on the `comments_votes` table.

Every 15 minutes, a scheduled task takes every comment created in the past 24 hours, then for each comment, a queue job is ran. The queued job then calculates the total score of the comment (total upvotes minus total downvotes) by querying all the `comment_votes` with that comment's ID.

I do this because I don't want to have to calculate the total_score of a comment every single time there's a new vote, as this would create a large amount of unnecessary queries.

However, the problem with this solution is that I'm also calculating comments that aren't receiving any votes.

I'm thinking I should maybe add a `total_votes` column to the `comments` table and have it so for the first 10 votes or something, a the queue job is ran at the time of voting. But if a comment has more total_votes than that, then it gets ran in the schedule task (along with all other comments with 10+ votes).

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is making some big assumptions on how your database is structured,

But you could do away with the whole scheduled task, background process, unless you are getting heaps of traffic, I don't think it will be an issue, databases are pretty fast when data is indexed.

If your comments_votes table has a column called vote, and that vote can be -1 for downvote and +1 for upvote, then you just need to do a SUM of all the votes

Then when you display your comments

```
select comments.comment, sum(comments_votes.vote) as total_votes
  from comments 
       left outer join comments_votes on comments_votes.comment_id = comments.id
```

make sure you have an index on comments_votes.comment_id so that the join is fast